# Matconvnet is not compiling with gpu using matlab 2019 b?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, gpu, conv-neural-network, matconvnet

I am using MATLAB 2019b, CUDA toolkit 10.1 and visual studio 2017.
I am able to compile the CPU version. but here is the error I get while compiling GPU version.

```
vl_compilenn('enableGpu', true, ...
```

'cudaRoot', 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1', ...
'cudaMethod', 'nvcc', ...
'enableCudnn', true, ...
'cudnnRoot', 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1');

the message error:
nvcc fatal   : '-DNDEBUG': expected a number
Error using vl_compilenn>nvcc_compile (line 615)
Command "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin\nvcc" -c -o
"G:\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\mex.build\bits\data.obj"
"G:\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\src\bits\data.cu" -DENABLE_GPU -DENABLE_DOUBLE -DENABLE_CUDNN
-I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\include" -O -DNDEBUG -D_FORCE_INLINES
--std=c++11 -I"G:\programme\extern\include" -I"G:\programme\toolbox\distcomp\gpu\extern\include"
-gencode=arch=compute_61,code="sm_61,compute_61"  --compiler-options=/MD

Comment: https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/issues/1212 and https://groups.google.com/g/matconvnet/c/TlLp9g7s-6g  seems like a defect in `vl_compilenn.m`

Comment: change `-O` to `-O3` [here](https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/blob/master/matlab/vl_compilenn.m#L340).